# Iframe Communication Checkbox Values

Tags: jquery, iframe, checkbox

On the parent page, I have a series of checkboxes like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="parlay" value=1>
<input type="checkbox" class="parlay" value=2>
<input type="checkbox" class="parlay" value=3>
```

On a certain event I pop an iframe, and need to get the values for all the checkboxes which are "checked" on the parent page. Can someone point me to a jQuery or Javascript approach for this problem?

Thanks much

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

Comment: Both pages are on the same page, this is not cross-domain.

Comment: I'm reading this two ways - either you open the iFrame with your page in it and want to send form data TO it - or you open another site's page and want to read the data on the page...with the user's consent of course.

Comment: I want to open a new page (on my side, same domain), and read all the values for checkboxes which are selected on the parent page. I *could* do this with a form but trying to get around that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**Javascript:**

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('CHECKBOX_ID').checked;
```

or

```
window.parent.document.getElementsByClassName('parlay').checked;
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input:checkbox.parlay', window.parent.document).prop('checked');
```

**Sample Code:**

```
$('input:checkbox.parlay').each(function () {
       var thisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
  });
```

**NOTE:**

[`document.getElementsByClassName(class)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

Be aware that some engines (particularly the older browsers) don't have it. I will suggest you to go with jQuery solution.

Comment: None of the checkboxes on the parent page have "ids" set, is there a jQuery way to get all the "checked" values for all checkboxes?

Comment: can you post your whole html like checkbox with parents (this is to check how easily we can access elements)

Comment: I like the Jquery approach, if there is more than 1 checkbox on the parent page, how can I loop through all of them?

Comment: I see it, thanks. I'm trying to output thisVal to the console, or an alert - but I'm not getting anything? Also - no syntax errors, so it looks like I'm just missing something obvious

Comment: Got it!  Needed to add the ", window.parent.document" to the Sample Code'